# How to get a integer value from JSON data in iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

I am parisng data using following date which is in JSON

```
[
 {
     "categoryId": 202,
     "name": "Sport"
 },
 {
     "categoryId": 320,
     "name": "Fritid"
 },
 {
     "categoryId": 350,
     "name": "Kultur"
 },
 {
     "categoryId": 4920,
     "name": "Diverse"
 },
 {
     "categoryId": 4774,
     "name": "Samfunn"
 } ]
```

Using Follwing Code

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.krsconnect.no/community/api.html?method=categories&appid=620&mainonly=true"]];
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *object = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
//appDelegate.books = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

appDelegate.books = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSArray *results = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
for (int i=0; i<[results count]; i++) {
    Book  *aBook = [[Book alloc] initWithDictionary:[results objectAtIndex:i]];
    [appDelegate.books addObject:aBook];


    [aBook release];

    }
```

Book Class

```
    @interface Book : NSObject {


NSString *catId;


NSString *name;

  }

     @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString*catId;

     @property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *name;

  @end


   #import "Book.h"


@implementation Book


@synthesize catId,name;

-(id)init{ 
    self=[super init];
}

- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*) dict {
   self.catId = [dict valueForKey:@"categoryId"];   self.name = 
   [dict valueForKey:@"name"];
   return self;
}
```

Comment: my question is that i am not getting value catid

Comment: i have given code of initWithDict

Comment: catid shows its not a CFSting

Comment: {categoryId = 202;
 name = Sport; },
{
        categoryId = 320;
        name = Fritid;
    },
        {
        categoryId = 350;
        name = Kultur;
    },
        {
        categoryId = 4920;
        name = Diverse;
    },
        {
        categoryId = 4774;
        name = Samfunn;
    }
)

Comment: this is result of nslog(@"%@",results);

Comment: Please can you tidy up the formatting of your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

that is because `CatId` is of tyoe `NSString`

Change it to `NSNumber` and try

Hope this helps.

Comment: if i use NSInteger it gives this value in catid 79765008

Comment: thats because its giving the address of the variable pointed by that variable

Comment: use intValue method on you nsinteger variable

Comment: intValue is working fine but i have five cate showing in tableview on cliking first cate it work but on other it gives exception

Comment: @robin: it's not an `NSInteger`, it's an `NSNumber`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are getting NSNumber when you parse the response for categoryId. So try by taking NSNumber object inplace of NSString.

Comment: can you help how to do like that i have done but not succeded

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary you are getting stores numeric values as `NSNumber` objects probably.  So your `catId` should either be a `NSNumber` too , or `-initWithDictionary:` should extract the category id into a primitive type using e.g. `-intValue` and catId should then be declared as `int`.

By the way, you should use `-objectForKey:` to get objects from `NSDictionary`s.  It's marginally more performant since `-valueForKey:` does some extra processing, then calls `-objectForKey:`.

Also `json_string` leaks and so robably does `appDelegate.books`.